# My ID keeps returning null

Tags: reactjs

I am learning ReactJS and attempting to console.log my id when the checkbox is checked. I have tried multiple ways to do this and I either get an error, undefined, or null. When it renders, the span tags do have their own id. How do I reference it from the function?

```
import React from "react";
import * as ToDoAction from "../actions/ToDoAction";

export default class ToDoLi extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    deleteToDo(){
        let id = document.getElementById('id');
        console.log('I am here at ' + id);
    }

    render(){

        return (
            <div>
                <li onChange={this.deleteToDo.bind(this)}><input type="checkbox"/><span id={this.props.id} className="m-l-10">{this.props.text}</span></li>
            </div>
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you render this `ToDoLi` component? PS: depending on what exactly you need to do - you must either use the `ref` or just extract data from the `props`, but definitely not `document.getElementById`

Comment: @zerkms I didn't realize I could extract the prop from the function. If you add your answer as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you could not find the element: most likely its `id` attribute value was not set to the `id` literally. To confirm that you need to provide how you render this component.

But this practice is highly discouraged, one should not mess with DOM directly.

What you should have done instead:

1. If you really need for some reason to get the dom element - learn how to use `ref`: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html
2. Alternatively you may want to explore through the event that is passed to a handler. For that declare your handler as `deleteToDo(e)` and inspect `e`
3. Otherwise - the `this.props` and all other react properties are available and you can use any of those.